# Add preview to new file type in Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder, quicklook

I'm developing an app that uses a new file type and extension. What controls the preview of the file in Finder? I know how to change the file icon to a custom icon, but to actually preview the file, like .jpg, .txt or .csv do? Is that managed by Quick Look or something?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=quick+look

Comment: Didn't even think of Quick Look until I was finishing writing the question :) Thanks!